# How to decrypt a string in cobol

Tags: .net, cobol, rijndaelmanaged

i'm looking for ways to decrypt a string in cobol that was encrypted in .net using RijndaelManaged. I have control of the algorithm so it doesn't need to be Rijdnael, but i just need to ensure that the data is encrypted.

Any help advice is appreciated.

Thanks
Sean

[Edit] - the data is encypted in a c# windows service that i've created. The data must be decrypted by a cobol system that will retreive the data from the windows service via tcpip. The encryption algorithm can be changed (in the windows service) and doesn't have to be Rijndael as long as cobol can decrypt it.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for: [Redvers Encryption Device](http://www.redversconsulting.com/data_encryption.php). It is a third party COBOL encryption package using the Rijdnael algroithm. I have never used this package so cannot comment on whether it is all the vendor cracks it up to be.

Depending on your implementation of COBOL, you may be able to call subroutines written in other languages to perform encyrption services. For example, Enterprise COBOL on z/os can call services written in just about any other language supported in the z/os environment.

Good luck.